# present a new ViewController but maintain the view stack

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to update an old IOS (objective-c) app to handle shortcutitems. When the user starts the app from a shortcut I would like to go the viewcontroller they've chosen, but would like them to be able to move back through the view hierarchy, to the original launch screen.

the current code in appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions looks like this:

```
UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
return YES
```

And trying this:

```
UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
...
if (fromShortCut) {
        InfoViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];
        // init vc
        vc.info = .....
        [controller.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
        // or [controller pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

    }
return YES
```

Shows the correct View, but there's no Back/Back-arrow or swipe gesture to allow the user to move back to the main screen.

Is this possible?

Many Thanks.

Comment: do not create a navigationcontroller every time use just navigationconroller in appDelegate , currently you are initializing new instance eveytime.

Comment: ok, but how does that actually help?

Comment: right now your code is showing  code  you are trying in didFinishLaunchoption 
am i right?

Comment: where is code under shortcutitems ?

Comment: Its the same code, I just haven't shown it

Comment: please show that too it will help because that is actual code where we need to remove navigationController initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for your solution

```
   if (fromShortCut) {
            InfoViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];
        UIViewController *rootController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
            // init vc
            vc.info = .....
[rootController.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
            [rootController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
            // or [controller pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

        }
else{
   UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
    }
```

Comment: Still the same - doesn't do what I want - I still have the view I wanted but no back stack. (just more optimally)

Comment: check navigationBar is hiddent or not? I also have updated answet with navigationBarhidden to NO

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This is possible.

`UINavigationController` has a `setViewControllers:animated:` method that lets you do exactly that.

Pay attention to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers?language=objc):

> **viewControllers**
>
> The view controllers to place in the stack. The
>   front-to-back order of the controllers in this array represents the
>   new bottom-to-top order of the controllers in the navigation stack.
>   Thus, the last item added to the array becomes the top item of the
>   navigation stack.

You should create an array of UIViewController objects and the order should like this.. [firstVC, secondVC, ..., topMostVC]

EDIT:
The code should look something like this

```
    UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
    if (fromShortCut) {
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //create other viewonctollerObjeccts
        FirstViewController *firstVC = storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first"];

        SecondViewController *secondVC = storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

        ThirdViewController *thirdVC = storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"third"];

        InfoViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];
        // init vc
        vc.info = .....
        [viewControllers insertObject:vc atIndex:0];

        //finally set the array to nav stack
        [controller setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
    }
```

What this does is, it sets InfoViewController at the top of the navigation stack, and backs out to ThirdViewController which backs out to SecondViewController and so on.

Comment: navigationController automatically manages hierarchy there is no need to keep track seprately just to come back if there is any other reason then you should keep track its just a burgen on memory and also extra work implementation

Comment: How would I use SetViewControllers, if I use it I still get the same problem?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I see your solution, I raise you "OP needs to maintain the navstack even if the navigation controller is not loaded".

Scenario here is that there is no back stack. But the normal UX must happen. For instance, A shortcut to a contact should show the contact detail, but backout to the "All Contacts".

Please provide an explanation to why this is a memory burden as well. I don't think this is the case, but I may have missed something.